# mkfs.ext4 command not available in fedora 8

Tags: fedora, ext4

Is ext4 file system supported on fedora 8? If yes, then how do i enable it?

I am unable to see format command for ext4. I can see only mkfs.ext3 and mkfs.ext2.

Answer (score 5):

[Fedora 8 was released on 8 November 2007](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Releases/8/Schedule)

[ext4 went stable on 21 October 2008](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext4)

So no, it did not include ext4 support.

I would say it's time to upgrade your system but honestly that time was 6 years ago already. :-)

Comment: Thankyou very much for the info. I will upgrade my OS. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

Check when fedora 8 and ext4 came out and you'll understand.

Ext4 support was experimental starting from fedora 9. It came being the default filesystem since fedora 11.

Also note this is an 7 years old distribution and fedora technical support is limited to Fedora 20 and 21.

Comment: Thankyou very much for the info. I will upgrade my OS. Thanks again.